# Match Cell, compare adjacent values, return non matches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets. I am trying to come up with a formula that looks for a sku match, once it find the matching sku, it then looks to see if the column "discontinued" is different for that sku, if so, display the result.

Table Old Database Snapshot:

```
skuID    sku    Discontinued 
00001    ASZ1   TRUE
00002    HSED1  FALSE
00003    SESG   TRUE
```

Table Most Recent Snapshot:

```
skuID    sku    Discontinued    Formula 
00001    ASZ1   FALSE           TRUE        
00002    HSED1  FALSE
00003    SESG   TRUE
```

I have a formula that does something similar, it looks for new sku's or sku's that have changed, but I can't figure out how to do this for this specific scenario.

Here are the different formulas I've been working with:
If I can incorporate it into this one, it will make the rest of the code a lot easier:

```
=IFERROR(IF(INDEX(Old!C2,MATCH(RC[-5],Old!C1,0))<>RC[-4],INDEX(Old!C2,MATCH(RC[-5],Old!C1,0)),""""),""SkuNew"")
```

I've also tried to rebuild the formula to simply how this works, which I have half built, I'm just trying to figure out how to now do a check on the "discontinued" part of the formula. Doesn't matter if its R1C1 or A1 as I will convert it once it goes into VBA.

```
=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(A2,Old!$A:$A,0))
```

Comment: Try this as an array formula entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER (change column C to whatever, if it's not that column): `=INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(A2&$C2,Old!$A:$A&Old!$C:$C,0))`

Comment: Alright so I have this working. Problem is this formula takes an extremely long time to run with many lines of code. Here is the finished result: =IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,MATCH(A2&$C2,Old!$A:$A&Old!$C:$C,0)),Old!$C2)

Comment: Roughly 40 minutes to refresh the formula.

Comment: How many rows/cells are you using this in? 40 *minutes*?  Something's not right. I've used a formula like that in maybe 300 cells before and it refreshes within a minute.

Comment: 70,000 rows. this plays into a much bigger project of making a comparison between snapshots of an entire product database. It looks for changes then alerts me when changes are made so that proper steps can be taken. (taking things off website that are discontinued, getting product information for new products, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vlookup with an if statement worked in this case.

"If when you look it up and get a match returns true, show nothing, if different, lookup the value in the Old Database Snapshot and return the value."

=IF(VLOOKUP(A2,Old!A:C,3,FALSE)=C2,"",VLOOKUP(A2,Old!A:C,3,FALSE))